# How do I update an SQL table from an excel spreadsheet?

Tags: sql, excel

I have an excel spreadsheet with 2 columns and 1000 rows. I need to update a table an SQL with the data. I basically need it updates the column B values for the adjacent values from column A. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: It does not see like too much data.  If this is one-time, and you have an interface to your DB, then export the data into text and write the sql update statement that you want.

Comment: Import the excel data to a temporary table and write an update query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard. You can feed it comma delineated files and if the first row has the column names. It will do just about everything for you.

[image]